# Extracting Specific Country from Continent Wide MapTiles

Tags: openmaptiles

Apologies for noob question, but I am no coder and total noob with MapTiles. I have a software that uses .mbtiles for a TileServer. I want to get a map of Algeria, but the price for the whole Continent is not much more than the country itself, so figured I'd buy whole Africa tiles, in case I need more countries in future.

If I purchase the Africa's OpenMapTiles (.mbtiles) would I be able to extract a specific country of it? If so, how can I go about it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know you can specify specific countries when hosting tiles and like you saw when purchasing. I would believe this is also possible.